# How do I make particles collide with object surfaces?

Tags: animation, particles, physics

[Please Refer to Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWU7cwsemoY&feature=youtu.be)
The blue cubes are using active rigid body properties. The red cubes are emitted using a particle system. The blue cubes are being affected by the surface of the yellow object, but the red particle cubes fall through. So my question is, how do I make particles collide with object surfaces?

Comment: The video is no longer available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable 'Collisions' on the object you want the particles to collide with on the 'Physics' tab:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple explanation. I should have been able to figure that one out by myself.